# error al querer instalar mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

tengo un pequeno gran problema, al querer instalar mongoDB me da un error "the windows installer servise could not be accessed. this can accur if you are running windows in safe mode, or if the windows installer is not correctly installed" si mi ingles no me falla es que al estar en modo seguro no se puede instalar, el problema es que mi pc tiene desactivado este modo, y ya no se que mas puede ser, si alguien me puede ayudar estaria agradecido

Comment: Anexa el mensaje de error.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes dar mucho más contexto a tu pregunta. Por otro lado, tu pregunta parece que va sobre algún problema de configuración de tu sistema operativo, lo cual no es exactamente parte de la temática del sitio. Tal vez si la realizas en [su] podrías tener alguna respuesta un poco más apropiada a tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Yo personalmente cuando usaba Windows TODO, absolutamente TODO, lo manejaba con el Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). [Instala WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/install) y prueba instalando mongodb en WSL.

WSL te permite instalar una distribución de Linux (yo te recomiendo Ubuntu) en tu computadora que te permite aislar un ambiente a tu sistema operativo Windows normal. De esta manera puedes tener 100% control de lo que pasa en esa distribución.

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta. Te invito a leer [answer] y a realizar el [tour]. La pregunta no está muy relacionada con la temática de [es.so] y/o está muy mal redactada, evitemos responder este tipo de preguntas.